# SoundCloud Play and Like Counts

Tags: java, javascript, php, json, soundcloud

Is it possible to retrieve Soundcloud Play and Like Counts for a single track with just the URL. I don't know if its php or java. I have a little knowledge of both.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: [Yes](https://developers.soundcloud.com/).

Comment: `Java` and `JavaScript` are not the same thing.  What language are you looking for an answer in?

Comment: I would prefer PHP cause I know more about it, but I'm willing to learn anything to accomplish what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check out the [Soundcloud HTTP API Reference](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks), you will see that the `/tracks` endpoint can provide you with the relevant values:

```
Name                Description             Example Value

playback_count      track play count        435
favoritings_count   track favoriting count  6
```

You can use the [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript) or the 3rd party [PHP SDK](https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud) to get these values.

[Here's an example JSON feed with the values you're looking for](http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/13158665.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID)

Comment: First thank you. I read the example you gave and the only thing is I need to use URL instead of track id

Comment: @famproent The trackid and permalink are interchangable in your fetch query. Try it out with [the console](https://developers.soundcloud.com/console) or [look at this example](https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/munching-at-tiannas-house.format?consumer_key=apigee), again [in JSON](https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/munching-at-tiannas-house.json?consumer_key=YOUR_CLIENT_ID)

Comment: I've read and compared both examples and to be honest I see the changes but not the URL like I sent you. Here's is what need to do. I have multiple artist on my label and I need to be able to pull the Plays, Likes and Downloads totals for each song and enter in a MySQL db table to store the results and a PHP in place to output the chart so I can send to the artist managers that are requesting it.

Comment: @famproent You haven't even sent me a URL, but the "permalink" is found inside this URL: `https://soundcloud.com/alex-stevenson/munching-at-tiannas-house`. If you can't deduce how to do things from this then I can't help you at all.